# Server-side url redirect

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

Hi all I need help with redirect in htaccess

My problem: how to get param3 value and redirect there in htaccess

From
https://exampletracking.com/track/?param1=value1&param2=value2&param3=https://example2.com/product/

to
https://example2.com/product/

I need help with redirect in htaccess, Because for Google Adwords need go redirection from tracking template to a product page server side. I don't have any experience with htaccess so can't really show any example for htaccess.

First I redirect client side with .JS code below successfully but google don't accepted because is client side redirect

```
var tracUrl = window.location.pathname;

var urlPath = document.location.protocol + "//" + document.location.hostname + "/" + document.location.search

var urlArray =  urlPath.split("param3=")[1].substring(0, 1000); 

location.replace(urlArray);
```

Im kinda stuck so for any help I will be grateful.

Comment: https://perishablepress.com/redirect-query-string-htaccess/

Comment: Even if i get one downvote for my question I am so glad that I asked, and link from Mr. Gurjar was beyond helpful. After many research I don't believe I will find this useful blog by myself.

Answer (score 0):

This work for me. Maybe will someone find also useful

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
# Redirect Query String (Apache 2.4)
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} param3=https://example2.com/([^/]+) [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) /%1 [R=301,L,QSD]
</IfModule>
```